# Не работает библиотека NCron из NuGet

Tags: c#, ncron

Пытаюсь задать выполнение метода про расписанию с помощью NCron:

```
public class DataUpdateJob : CronJob {
    public override void Execute() {
        Console.WriteLine("execute");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static Func<DataUpdateJob> f = new Func<DataUpdateJob>(() => { return new DataUpdateJob(); });
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var schedulingService = new SchedulingService();
        schedulingService.At("42 12 * * 1").Run(f);
        schedulingService.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все просто и должно работать. Если убрать часы и оставить только день недели и минуты то все работает, вот так: `"42 * * * 1"`. Почему с часами не работает?, это очень странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил так: Понизил версию в NuGet с **2.3.0** до **2.1.4281.39581**.

Comment: Если это регрессия, имеет смысл зарепортить им баг.